# Marketing Cloud UpsertContact only updates some records

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I have an email which executes an UpsertContact command to populate data in the Mobile demographics DE.

```
UpsertContact('mobile','phone',@phonecontact,'_timestamp', '06/10/17 at 11:00 AM')
```

Now there are actually more than contacts which have the same @phonecontact value but only 7 out of the 10 seem to update.

Can anyone explain what could be potentially cause this?

Comment: It's not clear since we don't see actual values. Could you give us an example of a contact that was updated and the one that wasn't? It seems that this function has some limitations. From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertcontact.htm) it says "Primary key type used to locate contact. Possible values include: phone" which probably means that if you are using primary keys other that phone numbers  then this function won't simply locate them. But this is just my assumption.

Comment: So I am using the phone as the method to upsert, without revealing real data I can tell you that `@phonecontact` is just a mobile number like `447123456789`. I should note there are many contacts with the same number but they all have different subscriber keys and ID's

Comment: Are you sure that phone number for those 3 contacts that were not updated is stored as the same attribute as for those 7 updated?

Comment: It definitely is as they come up when I search via the number, the number is also in the same fields (incase they are were found using another attribute)